# Authorize.net API gives null response on ChargeCreditCard

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have used authorize code for android from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/authorize/sample/PaymentTransactions/ChargeCreditCard.java

Once we excute below code

```
    //Common code to set for all requests
    ApiOperationBase.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX);

    MerchantAuthenticationType merchantAuthenticationType  = new MerchantAuthenticationType() ;
    merchantAuthenticationType.setName(apiLoginId);
    merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(transactionKey);
    ApiOperationBase.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);

    // Populate the payment data
    PaymentType paymentType = new PaymentType();
    CreditCardType creditCard = new CreditCardType();
    creditCard.setCardNumber("4242424242424242");
    creditCard.setExpirationDate("0822");
    paymentType.setCreditCard(creditCard);

    // Create the payment transaction request
    TransactionRequestType txnRequest = new TransactionRequestType();
    txnRequest.setTransactionType(TransactionTypeEnum.AUTH_CAPTURE_TRANSACTION.value());
    txnRequest.setPayment(paymentType);
    txnRequest.setAmount(new BigDecimal(amount).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));

    // Make the API Request
    CreateTransactionRequest apiRequest = new CreateTransactionRequest();
    apiRequest.setTransactionRequest(txnRequest);
    CreateTransactionController controller = new CreateTransactionController(apiRequest);
    controller.execute();


    CreateTransactionResponse response = controller.getApiResponse();
```

then the "response" it gives null response always.

Comment: Are you able to access https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api ?

Comment: It shows like : {"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00003","text":"Root element is missing."}]}}